# How does Killer Vegan skill work?

Tags: dungeons-of-dredmor

I am trying to understand what is the skill tree **Killer Vegan** and how does it work, unfortunately the two main wikis for Dungeon of Dredmor do not describe it.

[image]

Can you give me some hints?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are 5 skills under Killer Vegan.  The [Dredmor wiki](http://www.dredmorwiki.com/wiki/Killer_Vegan) has been updated with detailed information on these skills and debuffs.

- Green Harvest - You can eat non-living things for food, including the corpses of things like robots and demons.  There's a 50% chance of getting "Food" when you kill a non-living thing.  Killing vegetables has a chance to drop fruit.
- Animal Friend - Charm an animal (for 100 turns) to fight for you. (54 turn cooldown)
- Clean Living - You gain a health and health regen boost, in addition to +8 XP when you kill a vegetable.
- Aura of Self-Righteousness - Chance to do additional damage and blind (8%) when you attack.
- Level 5 Vegan - In addition to extra health benefits, you can activate the "Break the Circle of Life" skill every 120 turns.  This uncurses you, effectively removing any debuffs.

If you have Killer Vegan as a skill tree, and you injure an animal, you'll get a debuff of -5 to most of your primary skills, plus -5 health and mana regen for 200 turns.  This debuff stacks 3 times.  There's also a debuff for eating non-Vegan food, and another (more minor) debuff if you have Clean Living.

Comment: The penalty debuff for killing cute animals is harsh enough with beginning veganism. I'd hate to see how bad it gets later.

Comment: Is it possible that Killer Vegan skill enhance also your basic attributes?

Comment: Yes, for instance Clean Living enhances several.  Mostly they're focused on health and health regen stats.

Comment: Animal Friend doesn't summon an animal, it charms an existing one

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out.  I typed this based on the (relatively lame) descriptions of the skills in-game.  There are a couple of crashing bugs keeping me from making more progress in-game, unfortunately.