# What creatures count as cute animals for the Killer Vegan skill?

Tags: dungeons-of-dredmor

With the Killer Vegan set of skills killing cute animals results in a rather nasty debuff getting applied to your character. Which creature's deaths will trigger this?

Related: [How does Killer Vegan skill work?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/42924/how-does-killer-vegan-skill-work)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Monsters designated as 'animal' (rather than vegetable, undead, demon, etc...) may invoke the Fallen Vegan debuf.  Also, eating non-vegan foods (meats, cheeses, eggs) may invoke the debuf.